# Buscando elementos de uma matriz PHP

Tags: php

Minha função é esta e pega um número que o usuário digita e vê se corresponde a uma posição da matriz, caso seja verdade, exibiria as informações do array interno, mas as informações não são exibidas corretamente:

```
function localizar($id){

    echo "<h2>Resultado para o id $id:</h2>";

     for($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['array2']); $i++){            

        if($_SESSION['array2'][$i] = $id){

            for($s = 0; $s < count($_SESSION['array1'][$i]); $s++){

                $result = $_SESSION['array1'][$id][$i];

                break;

            }


            echo $result;

        }else{                      
            echo "Não encontramos correspondências";
        }


        echo "<br>";  


    }
```

Matriz:

```
function cadastrar($nome, $raca, $cor, $tipoPelo){

    $_SESSION['array1'][] = array($nome, $raca, $cor, $tipoPelo);

    $_SESSION['array2'][] = $_SESSION['array1'];


}
```

Como as informações são exibidas:

Gato 1
Raça 1

Como deveriam ser exibidas:

Gato 1
Raça 1
Cor 1
Tipo 1

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Primeiramente você não precisará fazer um loop para testar se a chave existe basta usar essa função que já faz isso:

array_key_exists
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-key-exists.php

Sabendo que a chave existe basta fazer o percorrer os dados, mas recomendo que faça com o foreach() e não com for(), porque dessa forma você não precisa se preocupar em contar os valores e sim só em percorrer eles.

Outro detalhe dentro do seu for() existe um break; que não deveria estar lá o loop está sendo executado mas está parando por causa disso.

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer dúvida chama ai